# Please help me with my proportions assignment for statistics

Tags: r, statistics

Dataset command:

```
download.file("http://www.openintro.org/stat/data/atheism.RData", destfile ="atheism.RData")
load("atheism.RData")
```

Question:
What is the proportion of atheists in the US according to the dataset ( as a percentage, round to 2 decimals)?

This is what I did:

I used the sum() function and got total number of atheists then I divided by the total of atheists+non-atheists. Does that sound right? For instance: (atheist)/(atheist+non-atheists)

My answer is:

0.05

2nd question that I would love help on:

What is the standard error for a confidence interval of the sample proportion of atheists (Round to 4 places)?

My answer: 0.0158

The formula is simply sqrt((p(1-p)/N)).

I don't think I was given p so I used 0.5 by default.
So, SQRT((0.5)(1-0.5)/1002)), I got 1002 from adding atheist+non-atheist and it is the total size N.

Seems right???

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a programming question. You might want to look at your text book for the answer of how to calculate a standard error based on sample proportion. Or potentially you could read the ?help.

Answer (score -2):

As @Elin said, this is more a Statistics problem, not a programming question. Also, open intro is a great text for stats, so go read that!

Now, since you're asking an R question, here's some info about R you should know to solve this. However, since it's HW, I wont write the solution for you. That's not going to help you long term!

First, to count how many elements have a certain level of a factor, you can take advantage of the fact that R treats boolean values as ones and zeros. So, you can sum the boolean vector to get a count.

For example, the iris dataset (see '?iris' for more details) has a factor Species. To get the number of the Species variables that have the level "setosa", run:

```
sum(iris$Species== "setosa")
```

To get the proportion you can divide by the length of the variable:

```
sum(iris$Species== "setosa") / length(iris$Species)
```

Note that for me `length(atheism$response)` returns 88032, not 1002. I get the same results by adding the two levels of atheism$response. I'd suggest you double check that this is the same dataset.

You need to calculate the standard error yourself. I recommend reading the text and the question carefully, as I suspect that 0.5 is not the correct value of p.

Also, a note about arithmetic in R. Order of operations is well specified but can be comfusing for new users. I'd recommend using parenthasis as much as possible. Also,, multiplication needs the '*' operator even when of the form a * (b + c) -- it's not assumed like it is in algebra a (b + c).

If you have more R questions, feel free to ask. But, you have to learn the statistics! And open intro is a great book so make good use of it!!!